# Google sign in issue with 12501 code in android app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

We are using Firebase as mBAAS and google sign in as an OAuth provider for our android app. It is working absolutely fine when one developer is working. When we are trying to do development on another machine, we are getting `12501` code on that new machine during google sign in.
We have added debug SHA key on firebase console and updated `google-services.json` that contains entries for both the client. We have also changed the client id when we are building the SignIn Option -

```
googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .requestIdToken(getResources().getString(R.string.client_id))
    .build();
```

How can I get this project to work on other development machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!!! as i was using `android-client-id` instead of `web-client-id`during `googleSignInOptions`.